# cases environment with material to the left rotated to vertical

Tags: vertical-alignment, cases

Say, I have this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\text{ three equations}
\begin{cases}
  a &= b + c \\
  d &= e + f + g \\
  h &= i + j + k + l
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

What I want is to set the text at the left of the big curly brace to be aligned vertically. I tried:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{equation*}
    %\text{ three equations}
    \begin{turn}{90}three equations\end{turn}
    \begin{cases}
    a &= b + c \\
    d &= e + f + g \\
    h &= i + j + k + l
    \end{cases}
    \end{equation*}
    
\end{document}
```

which aligns the LHS at the middle:

[image]

So, the problem is how to adjust the LHS automatically such that is aligned vertically?

Comment: Not solving your question, but I think the `&`s in the `cases` environment are useless.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}` to rotate content about it's `c`entre:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,makecell}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\[
  \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{three equations}
  \begin{cases}
    a = b + c         \\
    d = e + f + g     \\
    h = i + j + k + l
  \end{cases}
  \qquad
  \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\makecell{three \\ equations}}
  \begin{cases}
    a = b + c         \\
    d = e + f + g     \\
    h = i + j + k + l
  \end{cases}
\]

\end{document}
```